# Distribute outgoing connections among multiple IPs configured on the same NIC

Tags: networking, freebsd

I have a NIC with 2 aliases on it. The network interface has 3 IPs configured on it. Think about it like this: i can ping the same server by hitting .100 .101 and .102.

I want the source address of the outgoing connections to be distributed among these ip. So if i have 3 opened connections, one connection will have result as having an IP address ending with .100, the other two should result as having as ip addresses .101 and .102.

I'm using FreeBSD but I think this question to be Linux-Like wide.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Nothing you should worry about ;) I simply pay a service to have N number of multiple connections to their services, however there is an hard limit of 200 connections / source ip and I want to go over it. I pay in the end for what I use, don't worry ;) it's just that this would make me finish my project a week or so earlier.

Comment: What @SvenW said -- I see no benefit to this whatsoever.  You're not "load-balancing" anything: The limiting resource is usually uplink bandwidth. You could theoretically assign 4294967296 IPs to the same interface but you wouldn't get any more speed/redundancy out of it.

Comment: Hi, yes normally it wouldn't make any sense. In fact, it's a workaround =)

Comment: Usually the program you are using to open the client connection allows specifying the src address.

Comment: @cedivad Perhaps if you explain to us *why* you are doing this (what you're trying to work around) someone might give you an answer you can use -- as it is we're all kinda staring at this question like the twisted wreckage of a car after a freight train hits it (you can't look away, but you don't know why :-)

Comment: Using the word 'load balance' is just confusing the issue.  That is not what you mean.  In any case, what application are you using to make the outgoing connections?  If it happens to be HTTP, then there are proxies that may be able to do this.  If you are not using HTTP,  or some other protocol protocol which has a proxy to do this then you will probably have to do some NAT magic in the kernel.  The method to do this for Linux is completely different from what you would need to do on FreeBSD.

Comment: What is the client application.  Can you modify it?

Comment: It's a PHP application using Net_NNTP (and php's stream_socket_client()). I don't think that function to support the source ip to be set, unfortunately.

Comment: Wao, i discovered it to be possible =)